# how to link view controller and .xib file to tab bar item in xcode 4

Tags: iphone

I have a tab bar with 4 items and i want to link the .xib files to each item. The problem is that the NIB File Name shows no items, and if i write the .xib for example, StartView without the .xib i get an error. I get the same error when i link the tab item to the view controller class in the Identity Inspector. This is the error:

```
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "StartView" nib but the view outlet was not set.'
```

I had no problem with this in Xcode 3. As far as i know i don't need outlets in my view controller to be able to link a view to a bar item.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved, but i didn't like the solution. I created the view controller again and selected to create a .xib file along with the controller and that was it. Then i made the usual references from interface builder and it's working. I didn't like it because the .xib file has the same name as the view controller class. If anyone knows how to create the .xib file and the view controllers separately and get it to work, please inform me, i would really appreciate it.

Comment: This worked for me too, although I too find it odd that the template project uses "FirstViewController" and "FirstView.xib" naming convention, but the only way to add a third tab is to use the 'ThirdViewController' and 'ThirdViewController.xib' naming convention.

Answer (score 2):

Each .xib has a main view that must be connected to its files owner. Usually when you change the class name of a .xibs owner, the view outlet will become disconnected. So you'll want to first check that the class name of your .xib is the custom controller you have made. You then have to open the .xib and click on the connections inspector. Then just drag and connect the view outlet (labelled as view in the connections inspector) to your view.

Cheers.

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention that, i don't find the view outlet in the connections inspector check out the screen shot: http://www.box.net/shared/alu1eoby6a

Comment: Did you check the class name of your view controller in interface builder?

Comment: You can check the class of a xib file by opening up the xib, selecting the File's owner, and then the identity inspector (on the right hand utilities column in xcode 4).

Comment: You also want to make sure your class is a subclass of UIViewController. This is what gives IB the view outlet for you to assign to a view in the first place. You don't actually declare the view property, you inherit it.

Comment: That's just how i had it, that's why i find it so weird that it didn't work

Comment: zlog's answer helped me, but needed one more step: as zlog said- click files owner and under identity inspector set your class. You then need to right click on files owner and connect "view" to your xib view, and all should work fine

Answer (score 2):

select create new file, objective c, check the make xib file box and in the name of it, add .xib extension to the end of the  name